# problem with `hyperref` and TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I added "chapter" word to my TOC, but when i use package `hyperref`,this word remove from TOC. this is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref} % if commented all fine

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect{\numberline{\chaptername :  #1}}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\tableofcontents
\chapter{my name}
my name is ...
\section{structure}
\chapter{your name}
 your name is .....
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, `hyperref` usually is the last package loaded.

Comment: thanks, but don't repair

Comment: To be honest, i cannot figure out how you managed to write the word *chapter* to the contents. Can you strip down your example to make it real minimal? For example, most of the packages aren't needed.

Comment: I delete additional package. But this is minimal example.

Comment: do you have any code that do this work for me and don't have any problem whit 'hyperref'?

Comment: @mojtaba we will try

Comment: I know you can do it exactly

Comment: Ah, i was confused by `tartibi`. Out of interest, where does it come from?

Comment: @touhami Are you working on it? I can get some shopping done. :-)

Comment: i use xepersian package .`tartibi` come from here.

Comment: I do not understand the problem. It seems to me that the code work as expected.

Comment: @Johannes_B we need your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to patch `\@chapter` command befor loading `hyperref` but you will need somme extra space in `\l@chapter` you can do like this

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\chaptername}#1}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}}{\setlength\@tempdima{4.5em}}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\let\stdl@chapter\l@chapter
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{\stdl@chapter{{#1}}{}}
\makeatother

\tableofcontents
\chapter{my name}
my name is ...
\section{structure}
\chapter{your name}
 your name is .....
\end{document}
```

Comment: See, wasn't that hard. I just tried to patch around the `hyperref` internals. :-/ I should have seen that.

Comment: You could add that  `hyperref` redefines chapter, and many other commands,  to enable hyperlinking. It saves the original definition first.

Comment: @Johannes_B you are right, if you want to edit my answer, thank you.

Comment: very good , I think true that you can.thanks a lot @Johannes_B

Comment: This is indeed a way to go. Some remarks: (a) The chapter  number is gone, already a problem of the question. (b) `\@chapapp` is better than `\chaptername`, because it is automatically redefined for appendix chapters. (c) The 4th argument of `\patchcmd` should never be empty. A simple error message `\errmessage{Patching of \noexpand\@chapter failed}` will inform the user, if the `\patchcmd` was not successful. (d) The original `\@chapter` command contains *three* versions of `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}` for different cases, not just one.

Comment: @mojtaba please see  Heiko Oberdiek's comment

Comment: thanks all. but there is a problem. i want so remove number of chapter page from table of contacts. please

Comment: @mojtabamansouri you need to spresse the page number of all chapters from table of contents

Comment: yes. @touhami by your permit, i add some code to your code for remove number of chapter page from table of contacts. thanks for your help

Comment: @mojtabamansouri i aproved your edit, another way is to add `\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\hss #2}{}{}{}`